# Deserialize json with Json.NET

Tags: c#, json.net, philips-hue

I have JSON that looks like this (from the Philips HUE API):

```
{
    "1": {"name": "Bedroom"},
    "2": {"name": "Kitchen"}
}
```

When I try to deserialize this document I run into problems because the document is structured the way it is.

If it had been formated like this:

```
[
   {"nr": "1", "name": "Bedroom"},
   {"nr": "2", "name": "Kitchen"}
]
```

Everything would have been fine. Now I am forced to do string parsing in order to extract the data... :-(

Any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would deserialize to `JObject` and use it as `Dictionary`

```
var jObj = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
Console.WriteLine(jObj["1"]["name"]);
```

or

```
dynamic jObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
Console.WriteLine(jObj["1"].name);
```

Comment: Thanks! I will work with the dynamic approach and see what I can do with it.